# download the entire Google cloud storage folder

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have a real need to download entirely a folder on google cloud storage. The message that pops up is that it is possible to download every single item.
I have downloaded the Google Cloud SDK software, but I am unable to run the download everything command. A million errors appear. Can you kindly help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: "*but I am unable to run the download everything command*" - this in unclear.  Please edit the question to explain what exactly you tried that doesn't work the way you expect, along with any error message or other information that we can work with.

Comment: Dear Doug, Thank you for your reply. I have never used the console SDK. I have installed it and logged in. Now, I tried to copy the text that google suggests to download my bucket locally, but errors appear (it seems you can't write commands on two lines). I simply need to download the entire bucket to my desktop (any folder will do) as it is a qnap backup that I then need to unzip. Sorry but I am very agitated because due to a ramsoware I lost all